# What's the difference between abs and fabs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cmath

I checked the difference between `abs` and `fabs` on python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994052/abs-vs-fabs-speed-difference-and-advantage-of-fabs)

As I understand there are some difference regarding the speed and the passed types, but my question related to native c++ on V.S.

Regarding the V.S.
I tried the following on `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)`:

```
float f1= abs(-9.2); // f = 9.2
float f2= fabs(-9); // Compile error [*]
```

So `fabs(-9)` it will give me a compiler error, but when I tried to do the following:

```
double i = -9;
float f2= fabs(i); // This will work fine
```

What I understand from the first code that it will not compile because `fabs(-9)` need a double, and the compiler could not convert -9 to -9.0, but in the second code the compiler will convert `i=-9` to `i=-9.0` at compile time so `fabs(i)` will work fine.

Any better explanation?

Another thing, why the compiler can't accept  `fabs(-9)` and convert the int value to double automatically like what we have in c#?

```
[*]:

Error: more than one instance of overloaded function "fabs" matches the argument list:
        function "fabs(double _X)"
        function "fabs(float _X)"
        function "fabs(long double _X)"
        argument types are: (int)
```

Comment: No compiler errors here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80c5484bda892461

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In C++, `std::abs` is overloaded for both signed integer and floating point types. `std::fabs` only deals with floating point types (pre C++11). Note that the `std::` is important; the C function `::abs` that is commonly available for legacy reasons will only handle `int`!

The problem with

```
float f2= fabs(-9);
```

is not that there is no conversion from `int` (the type of `-9`) to `double`, but that the compiler does not know which conversion to pick (`int` -> `float`, `double`, `long double`) since there is a `std::fabs` for each of those three. Your workaround explicitly tells the compiler to use the `int` -> `double` conversion, so the ambiguity goes away.

C++11 solves this by adding `double fabs( Integral arg );` which will return the `abs` of any integer type converted to `double`. Apparently, this overload is also available in C++98 mode with libstdc++ and libc++.

In general, just use `std::abs`, it will do the right thing. ([Interesting pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750946/is-stdabs0u-ill-formed) pointed out by [@Shafik Yaghmour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708801/shafik-yaghmour). Unsigned integer types do funny things in C++.)

Comment: *In general, just use std::abs, it will do the right thing.* ...  see [Is std::abs(0u) ill-formed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29750946/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Interesting, I never ran into that. It's amazing how much havoc unsigned integers cause in C++. The "correct" implementation that converts the unsigned integer to `double` is not what I would expect that code to do TBH.

Comment: Don't get my wrong this is a good answer, I ran into this accidentally and it is good to be aware of especially since there is implementation variance and it is still open.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Agreed, I added a remark to the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 17):

With C++ 11, using `abs()` alone is very dangerous:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::cout << abs(-2.5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs `2` as a result. ([See it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DaeVKbzgQBx6rYeW))

Always use `std::abs()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::abs(-2.5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program outputs `2.5`.

You can avoid the unexpected result with `using namespace std;` but I would adwise against it, because it is considered bad practice in general, and because you have to search for the `using` directive to know if `abs()` means the `int` overload or the `double` overload.

Comment: I've found the same problem. For me both abs() and std::abs() loses the decimal part. fabs() works though. Any idea why?

Comment: @jmoraal Sorry, no, I don't know about something that could cause this... Old compiler, maybe? You could post this as a question and include all details, like the code, and the compiler used.

Answer (score 3):

My Visual C++ 2008 didn't know which to choice from `long double fabs(long double)`, `float fabs(float)`, or `double fabs(double)`.

In the statement `double i = -9;`, the compiler will know that `-9` should be converted to `double` because the type of `i` is `double`.

---

`abs()` is declared in `stdlib.h` and it will deal with `int` value.

`fabs()` is declared in `math.h` and it will deal with `double` value.

Comment: in C++ `abs` and `fabs` are both in `<cmath>`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs

Comment: @NathanOliver `std::abs` and `std::fabs` are. The others can be, but don't have to be.