# Is there any difference between std::abs and std::fabs when applied to floating point values?

Tags: c++, floating-point, absolute-value

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118165/when-do-i-use-fabs-and-when-is-it-sufficient-to-use-stdabs) but I believe it doesn't answer this question.

Looking at [`std::abs` and `std::fabs` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) they seems to have exactly the same behaviour. As a personal note, it appears to me that `std::fabs` is preferable because it mitigates the ambiguity with the `std::abs(int)` definition in `<cstdlib>`(See [note](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs#Notes)).

So my question is: besides the `std::abs(int)` potential ambiguity, is there any difference at all between `std::abs` and `std::fabs` when applied to floating point values?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738509/whats-the-difference-between-abs-vs-fabs-in-c

Comment: I don't know how you cannot see it. `std::abs` and `std::fabs` have identical behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In standard-conforming code that has included `cmath` and only calls `std::abs` on `float`s, `double`s, and `long double`s, there is no difference.  However, it is instructive to look at the types returned by `std::abs` on various types when you call it with various sets of header files included.

On my system, `std::abs(-42)` is a `double` if I've included `cmath` but not `cstdlib`, an `int` if I've included `cstdlib`, and it produces a compilation error if I've included neither.  Conversely, `std::abs(-42.0)` produces a compilation error (ambiguous overload) if I've included `cstdlib` but I haven't included `cmath` or a different compilation error (never heard of `std::abs`) if I've included neither.

On my platform, `std::abs('x')` gives me a `double` if I've included `cmath` or an `int` if I've included `cstdlib` but not `cmath`.  Similar for a `short int`.  Signedness does not appear to matter.

On my platform, the `complex` header apparently causes both the integral and the floating-point overloads of `std::abs` to be declared.  I'm not certain this is mandated; perhaps you can find an otherwise reasonable platform on which `std::abs(1e222)` returns infinity with the wrong set of standard headers included.

---

The usual consequence of "you forgot a header in your program" is a compilation failure complaining of an undefined symbol, not a silent change in behaviour.  With `std::abs`, however, the result can be `std::abs(42)` returning a `double` if you forgot `cstdlib` or `std::abs('x')` returning an `int` if you didn't.  (Or perhaps you expected `std::abs` to give you an integral type when you pass it a `short`?  Then, assuming my compiler got its promotion and overload resolution right, you had better make sure you don't include `cmath`.)

I have also spent too much time in the past trying to work out why code like `double precise_sine = std::sin(myfloat)` gives imprecise results.  Because I don't like wasting my time on these sorts of surprises, I tend to avoid the overloaded variants of standard C functions in `namespace std`.  That is, I use `::fabs` when I want a `double` to be returned, `::fabsf` when I want a `float` out, and `::fabsl` when I want a `long double` out.  Similarly for `::abs` when I want an `int`, `::absl` when I want a `long`, and `::absll` when I want a `long long`.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any difference at all between std::abs and std::fabs when applied to floating point values?

No there is not. Nor is there a difference for integral types.

It is idiomatic to use `std::abs()` because it is closest to the commonly used mathematical nomenclature.