# Reason for Overflow (G++ vs Clang++)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, clang++

When I'm compiling the following piece of C++ code using Clang++ and G++

```
void ScaleFactor(float32_t scale, int32_t &factor) {
    factor = floor(log2(abs(scale))+1)
    cout << factor << endl;
}
```

where the value of `scale` equals 0.234375 and `factor` is passed by reference to an integer variable in another function, I'm getting the following different outputs for `factor` while debugging using GDB

```
(int32_t &) @0x7fffffffdaa0: -2147483648 (Clang++)
(int32_t &) @0x7fffffffda9c: -2 (G++)
```

But, on replacing `abs()` with `fabs()` each output matches with the desired output

```
(int32_t &) @0x7fffffffdb90: -2 (Clang++)
(int32_t &) @0x7fffffffdddc: -2 (G++)
```

What might be the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: What values are you calling the function with?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that! Value scale is 0.234375 and factor is just a reference to an integer variable.

Comment: Recommendation: Cut the program down to `ScaleFactor` and a simple `main` that only exists to call `ScaleFactor` with your fixed inputs. If you get the same results, post this little program so we can all run it and see. If the problem goes away, yousa got a bug, but it's not where yousa thinks it is.

Comment: Where does `float32_t` come from?

Comment: Where is the [mcve], command line, warnings, etc? This is relevant, the answer may depend on your exact list of #include.

Comment: Try and add this: `cout << abs(0.5f) << endl;` right after your output. If you get 0, you're surely including the wrong math functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738509/whats-the-difference-between-abs-and-fabs) to this post.  `abs` is generally for integers and `fabs` is for floating point types.  However, it looks like G++ implementation of `abs` will handle floats, too.

Answer (score 1):

Does this code produce the same results? It does not seem to, for me: https://godbolt.org/z/Wj9v6j

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

using float32_t = float;

void ScaleFactor(float32_t scale, int32_t &factor) {
    factor = floor(log2(abs(/*(int)*/scale))+1);
    cout << factor << endl;
}


int main() {
    int32_t result;
    ScaleFactor(0.234375f, result);
    return 0;
}
```

If it does not, are you sure that something else is not going wrong here? Maybe you are including the C versions of the math functions, where there is a difference between abs and fabs, when building with clang?

The weird result you get is exactly what I get if I cast the float to int when passing it to abs, exactly what you would expect if you were using the C version of abs.

Comment: And I'll bet you $42 more  that, when it does, what's left in its place will have the same exact value as it would have returned.

Comment: I just took your godbolt link, replaced cmath with math.h, removed all the iostream stuff, removed the `using namespace std`,  and `std::abs` [still got 
called](https://godbolt.org/z/C2rkuX). Wasn't expecting that. Was expecting a failure to compile (no `int32_t`). Wonder what's up.

Comment: Well. That was easy. Inside math.h is a `# include <cmath>`. Probably a cstdint include in there somewhere.